# Espresso.onData set inAdapterView to be AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-testing, android-espresso, android-adapterview

I have an AlertDialog that contains a list of options which is set:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(args.getString(TITLE))                    
                .setSingleChoiceItems(ARRAY_OF_CHARSEQUENCE, args.getInt(SELECTED_INDEX), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // handle click
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

I am trying to test clicking on each item.
If I run:

```
onView(allOf(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(AppCompatCheckedTextView.class.getName())), withText(displayName)))
                .perform(click());
```

Things work wonderfully, except if the list of options in the AlertDialog is too long to display entirely.

So, I am trying to find the item by using onData instead, but I am unsure how to instruct the DataInteraction object created by onData in what view to look for the data.

The AppCompatCheckedTextView objects that I am trying to click on are contained by an AlertController$RecyleListView with ID select_dialog_listview. So, I have tried:

```
onData(withText(displayName))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.select_dialog_listview)) 
                .perform(click());
```

and

```
onData(withText(displayName))
                .inAdapterView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo("android.internal.app.AlertController$RecyleListView")))
                .perform(click());
```

But receive an error that there is no matching view in the hierarchy.

So, then I tried adding a custom view to the Alert Dialog to see if I could find that by ID.

I have a layout file containing only a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_view">
</LinearLayout>
```

Which I add to my AlertDialog builder:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .setTitle(args.getString(TITLE))
                    .setView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_view, null))                    
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(ARRAY_OF_CHARSEQUENCE, args.getInt(SELECTED_INDEX), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // handle click
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

And then look for in Espresso:

```
onData(withText(displayName))
                    .inAdapterView(withId(R.dialog_view)) 
                    .perform(click());
```

But receive the error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: org.OUR.APPLICATION:id/dialog_view'.
```

If I am correct in using onData to perform the click, what is the proper method of pointing DataInteraction to the AlertDialog view.

Comment: instead of `onData` try to use `onView(withText(R.string.test_account)).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
`

Comment: I wasn't aware of using isDialog with inRoot, that's good to know.
But it doesn't address the base problem of using onView in this situation: visibility. Using onView will only match Views that are at least partially visible. That's why I was attempting to use onData, so I could search for the correct item without regard to visibility.

Comment: Use `UiAtomator` to help `Espresso` :
http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

Answer (score 4):

onData() with "com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView" does work for me, note that you have typo in "RecyleListView".

Also, onData() parameter should be "dataMatcher", instanceOf() on the type used as T for ArrayAdapter (String in this case) works.

This works for me:

```
onData(is(instanceOf(String.class))).inAdapterView(allOf(withClassName(equalTo("com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView")), isDisplayed())).atPosition(index).perform(click());
```