# Clicking on alert dialog contents using Espresso or UIautomator

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

So, I am creating test cases using both UiAutomator and Espresso and I need to handle these items that appear in the alert dialog. The problem I am having is that I have only limited information since the code uses AlertDialog builder to add items to the list (app behaviour).

Moreover, I don't even have the information on the title of the alert dialog. Is there a way to handle these items by index and not text? 
[image: A wild dialog appears!]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Espresso.onData set inAdapterView to be AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959280/espresso-ondata-set-inadapterview-to-be-alertdialog)